# Fastening Double Ledger board for deck

Tags: deck, ledger

I'm building a new deck and got my plans approved for the city. In order to reduce the point load from a beam meeting on the corner of the house, the inspector asked that I use a double ledger board and move the footing closer to the foundation. How do I attach a double ledger? Do I attach one with galvanized lag screws to the rim joist, and then attach the other ledger to that, or should I just put galvanized lag screws through both ledgers at once into the rim joist? Also, Menards and Home Depot sell mostly "galvanized 1/2" lag screws", but the code calls for "hot dipped galvanized". Can someone explain the difference? Are the galvanized they're selling at the hardware stores really hot dipped galvanized and they're just shortening the name, or is it something else?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Galvanized just means there is a layer of zinc on top - hot-dip means it was dipped into a bath of molten zinc, leaving a thick, usually slightly bumpy layer of zinc all over the nail.  The other main type of galvanization is electroplating, which leaves a generally thin, smooth and shiny surface layer.

Comment: So, as you call it, the “double ledger board” is going to cantilever from the footing (that is moved closer to the corner), over to the corner?

Comment: What size ledger boards?

Comment: @LeeSam the ledger boards are 2x10. No, the double ledger board is attached to the rim joist (which sits on the foundation). The beam will then extend past the footing and anchor to the double ledger board. The issue was that typically creates a large point load on the rim joist of the house, so to reduce that they requested a "double ledger board".